# Firebase JobDispatcher : How to reschedule the same job?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher

I'm new to the JobDispatcher and so I'm not pretty sure whether my question makes sense or not.

I have a requirement where I need to run some tasks periodically in the background (even if the App is not running).
The task is not executing in a fixed time interval. On executing task for the first time , I'll get to know the schedule of the next task execution, So after the first execution, I should re-schedule the same task to a next time in future, which I will
get to know after completing the task. And it goes on like this.

Its like syncing something from network , and the network data will tell when to sync next.

So, My questions are

Should I create a new Job each time for each new task?

Can I create repeating job and keep on changing the interval?

How can I deal with this scenario exactly with FireBaseJobDispatcher.

I chose FireBaseJobDispatcher over JobScheduler because my App has to support below Lollipop also.

Here is a sample code I tried with FireBaseJobDispatcher with executing a task at a given time, and its working fine. Now I'm stuck how to re-schedule it to the next syncing time.

```
        public class MyJobService extends JobService {
            private static final String TAG = "MyJobService";
            @Override
            public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters job) {
                // Do some work here
                Log.d(TAG, "onStartJob: at "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
               new Thread(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       Log.d(TAG, "run: startign job ");
                       try {
                           Thread.sleep(2000);
                           // some syncing operation
                       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                       Log.d(TAG, "run: job done");
                       // here I need to reschedule the same job to a future time

                   }
               }).start();
                return false; 
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onStopJob: ");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I'm setting the Job in the activity like this

```
   // Create a new dispatcher using the Google Play driver.
    FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(this));
    Bundle myExtrasBundle = new Bundle();
    myExtrasBundle.putString("some_key", "some_value");

    Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            .setService(MyJobService.class)
            .setTag("syncservice")
            .setRecurring(true)
            .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
            .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(1*60*60 , 1*60*60)) // rigger after an hour
            // don't overwrite an existing job with the same tag
            .setReplaceCurrent(false)
            // retry with exponential backoff
            .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
            .setConstraints(
                    Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK
            )
            .setExtras(myExtrasBundle)
            .build();

    dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```

Thanks In advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
  Log.d(TAG, "onStopJob: ");
  if(rescheduleJob)
    return true; // reschedule job
  else
    return false; // cancel job
}
```

Or you can try :

```
@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
  Log.d(TAG, "onStopJob: ");
  return rescheduleJob;
}
```